# Ionic Angular JS navigation item not navigating

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I currently have other pages in my application that navigate fine, but I have added a new tab and when I click it, it's just closing the menu and not going to the page. I cannot work out why... Can anyone see?

**app.js :**

```
 .state('utab.history', {
    url: '/history',
    views: {
      'utab-login': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/history.html',
        controller: 'HistoryCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

**Controller :**

```
 $scope.historyClick=function(){
        console.log("historyClick");
        $state.go('utab.history');

    };

.controller('HistoryCtrl', function($scope,$state,AppServer,AppHelper,AppStorage,$http) {
    alert("yo2");
})
```

And the **html** code in the navigation :

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-left" nav-clear="" menu-close="" ui-sref="utab.history" ng-click="historyClick()">
          <i class="icon ion-document"></i>
          <h2 class="menu-text">History</h2>
        </ion-item>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your  .state('utab') look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible you have some conflict.

Both menu-close, ui-sref, ng-click are probably listening for click event. If menu-close cancel the event after handling it, you're screwed.

Try `ng-click="historyClick($event)"` and remove menu-close and ui-sref, so you may try to get the item from $event in order to close the menu and navigate.

ANother possibility : split each directive in separate DOM elements to handle the click, with menu-close at the higher level i think.